# Alternatives to compiling in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

The following situation will surely be familiar to any Android developer using Eclipse and ADT.

I'm tired of this endless cycle of switching Build Automatically on and off, running Clean, building and running. I'm constantly doing all of these operations when I'm fine tuning UI (i.e., editing XML files and needing to see the results live), and any time I save, an Eclipse window telling me I have these pending operations shows up. When that happens, I turn off Build Automatically. I do my alterations and then run. Sometimes Eclipse decides the changes in the XML file weren't enough, and it won't reinstall the app in the emulator or device, so I force a build and install.

All of this is just wasted time. I've already done an AppleScript to build & run my app into all the emulators and devices I have connected at once, described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968926/in-eclipse-any-way-to-start-application-in-more-than-one-emulator-at-the-same-ti), but my workflow could be much improved if I found a way to save and build silently and fast.

Does anyone have any tips or alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[IntelliJIdea Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) now supports Android

Comment: That actually looks pretty awesome. I'll have to give that a try.

Comment: Yay! Finally they got around to supporting the latest SDK!

Comment: I think both the bundle for Textmate and IntelliJIdea's Community Edition are valid answers, however the bundle doesn't support the newest version of the SDK and IntelliJIdea is a fantastic Java IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [bundle for Textmate](http://www.onebitwonder.com/projects/android)? It's pretty cool. It's basic but its got all the features you need. Building, Deployment and integration with AVD and Logcat.

I use this for all my Android Dev now as I found Eclipse painfully slow.